# Makefile 'undefined reference while linking'

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, undefined-reference

First time in my life I have to use Makefile on big project (it is using `ncurses`). This is my Makefile:

```
PROGRAM=go

CC=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb
LCUR=-lncurses

all: compile

run: compile
    ./$(PROGRAM)

compile: $(PROGRAM)


$(PROGRAM): objs/main.o objs/game.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LCUR)

objs/main.o: src/main.cpp | objs
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LCUR)

objs/game.o: src/Token.cpp src/GoSocket.cpp src/GoSerializer.cpp src/GoMenu.cpp src/Points.cpp src/Player.cpp src/LocalPlayer.cpp src/LanPlayer.cpp src/RandomAIPlayer.cpp src/SatisfactoryAIPlayer.cpp src/GoRulesChecker.cpp  src/GoLanGame.cpp src/GameBoard.cpp src/Game.cpp | objs
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LCUR)


objs: 
    mkdir objs

clean:
rm -rf $(PROGRAM) objs/ doc/ 2>/dev/null
```

I'm everything goes just fine, until the `$(PROGRAM)` final linking where I get a wall of errors:

```
~/ClionProjects/gj $ make compile
mkdir objs
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -c src/main.cpp -o objs/main.o -lncurses
In file included from src/main.cpp:3:0:
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     };
     ^
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/GoMenu.h:49:5: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -c src/Token.cpp -o objs/game.o -lncurses
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -g -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb objs/main.o objs/game.o -o go -lncurses
objs/main.o: In function `announceScore(Player*, Player*)':
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `GoMenu::GoMenu()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
objs/main.o: In function `main':
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `GoMenu::GoMenu()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:52: undefined reference to `GoMenu::show()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:53: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:54: undefined reference to `GoMenu::choose() const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:62: undefined reference to `Game::Game(Player&, Player&, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:69: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:73: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:82: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `GoSocket::GoSocket(std::string const&, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:88: undefined reference to `GoSocket::tryConnect()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:94: undefined reference to `GoSocket::readMessage() const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:104: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:105: undefined reference to `GameBoard::render()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:106: undefined reference to `GoLanGame::GoLanGame(GameBoard&, GoSocket&, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `GoLanGame::loop()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:108: undefined reference to `GoLanGame::isRunning()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `GoSocket::~GoSocket()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:126: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:127: undefined reference to `SatisfactoryAIPlayer::SatisfactoryAIPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:128: undefined reference to `GameBoard::setBlackSurrender(bool)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:129: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:130: undefined reference to `Game::Game(Player&, Player&, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:135: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:136: undefined reference to `RandomAIPlayer::RandomAIPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:137: undefined reference to `GameBoard::setBlackSurrender(bool)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:138: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:139: undefined reference to `Game::Game(Player&, Player&, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:151: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:158: undefined reference to `GoSerializer::Deserialize(std::string const&, int*, int*) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:161: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:173: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int, int***)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:174: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:175: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:176: undefined reference to `Game::Game(Player&, Player&, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:184: undefined reference to `GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:185: undefined reference to `GoSocket::GoSocket(std::string const&, int)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:186: undefined reference to `GoSocket::start()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:187: undefined reference to `GoMenu::showMessage(std::string const&) const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:188: undefined reference to `GoSocket::waitForClient()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:191: undefined reference to `GameBoard::getRows()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:193: undefined reference to `GameBoard::getCols()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:196: undefined reference to `GoSocket::writeMessage(std::string const&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:198: undefined reference to `LocalPlayer::LocalPlayer(int, int, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:199: undefined reference to `LanPlayer::LanPlayer(int, int, GoSocket&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:200: undefined reference to `Game::Game(Player&, Player&, GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:201: undefined reference to `Game::setNetwork(bool)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:202: undefined reference to `Game::setSocket(GoSocket*)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:202: undefined reference to `GoSocket::~GoSocket()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:205: undefined reference to `GameBoard::render()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:217: undefined reference to `Game::doLogic()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:219: undefined reference to `GoRulesChecker::GoRulesChecker(GameBoard&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:221: undefined reference to `GameBoard::getArray()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:221: undefined reference to `GoRulesChecker::checkRules(int***, std::list<Token, std::allocator<Token> >&)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:222: undefined reference to `GameBoard::render(std::list<Token, std::allocator<Token> >*)'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:224: undefined reference to `GameBoard::WhiteSurrender()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:224: undefined reference to `GameBoard::BlackSurreder()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:237: undefined reference to `Game::getTurn() const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:241: undefined reference to `Game::getTurn() const'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:215: undefined reference to `Game::isRunning()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:251: undefined reference to `GameBoard::~GameBoard()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:259: undefined reference to `Game::~Game()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:109: undefined reference to `GoSocket::~GoSocket()'
/home/mint/ClionProjects/gj/src/main.cpp:202: undefined reference to `GoSocket::~GoSocket()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [go] Error 1
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is thinking that a single target, `game.o` gets compiled from a large list of different translation units; nearly a dozen of them. C++ compilers don't work that way. Each `.cpp` file gets compiled into its own `.o` file. You need a `.o` file for every `.cpp` file.

Comment: adding to the above: you probably want to use a pattern rule, e.g. `objs/%.o: src/%.c:`, and put your list of object somewhere that you can use as prerequisites for the link step

Comment: let me make sure I'm getting it right. i should make .o files one by one for every .cpp file, regardless of their dependency on eachother and then link it all together in one step?

Comment: Exactly. Each object files refer to the others so the linker needs all the object files to work, not only the one you consider as the final one.

Comment: Thank you all guys and sorry for shitty post, I was really in a hurry because of deadline. Looked for wildcard in Makefile and solved by one command to compile .cpp files separately. Thanks !